# JQGrid Loads 28k+ records on local dev machine but no records on server

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have implemented JQGrid + MVC + Jason, that loads the data of more than 28000 on the grid, when i run the application on local machine.  But Grid doesn't load the data when i deploy on any of the server with no code/configuration change.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have any error in F12 Developer tools console? Check your Script URLs, probably in your local you might have paths hardcoded. Also try with limited data set on server, it could be DB Timeout as well.

Comment: You should include JavaScript code which you use to create jqGrid and the example of 2-3 lines of test data which shows the JSON format which you use. Moreover it's unclear whether you just have some common problem with URL or you have jqGrid problem.

Comment: return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oReviewExcessResultlst);
            // where oReviewExcessResultlst is generic list and function retutn type string/Json

Comment: the usage of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is wrong in the most cases. The controller action should return `JsonResult` and you need to use something like ` return Json(oReviewExcessResultlst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. So it's really important that you includes the code which you use in the text of your question. It could be important to know which version of jqGrid you use.